# how to multiply two tables in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have two data files like this:

file1:

```
  a1    a2  a3  ... aN
  b1    b2  b3  ... bN
  .
  .
  .
```

file1:

```
  A1    A2  A3  ... AN
  B1    B2  B3  ... BN
  .
  .
  .
```

I want to multiply the two tables, i.e.,

```
  a1*A1 a2*A2   a3*A3   ... aN*AN
  b1*B1 b2*B2   b3*B3   ... bN*BN
  .
  .
  .
```

Can I do it with AWK or something else in BASH? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried this in R. Yes, it's really easy in R, but I hope to do it in BASH so that this step can be integrated to my data analysis pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`, assuming you have the same number of fields and rows in each file. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[NR][i]=$i
    }
    next
}

{
    for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
        $j = $j * a[FNR][j]
    }
}1
```

Alternatively, here's the one liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR][i]=$i; next } { for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) $j = $j * a[FNR][j] }1' file1 file2
```

Testing:

Contents of `file1`:

```
1 2 3   
2 4 6
```

Contents of `file2`:

```
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Results:

```
3 8 15
12 28 48
```

---

***EDIT:***

If, and I mean if, there could be extra fields that one file has that the other doesn't, change:

```
$j = $j * a[FNR][j]
```

to:

```
$j = (a[FNR][j] ? $j * a[FNR][j] : $j)
```

This will print the existing value and not zero. HTH.